# How to replace rows with latest date in SAS

Tags: sas

I have a SAS dataset which contains quarterly data which I'm trying to use. I have uploaded the historical data going back 5 years and I'll be getting quarterly data which will continue to roll over through out the year.

For example in the current year 2023

| End Date | Group |
| --- | --- |
| 30 June-23 | Commercial |
| 30 June-23 | Commercial |

Next dataset I'll receive will have rows with data with End Date as 30th September.

How would i be able to drop the rows from the previous dataset and replace this with the new rolled over data for september in SAS?

Thanks!

Sorry i'm quite new to SAS so all I managed to do so far is to import the file but stuck with all the date parameters in creating a macro with dates and then delete/replace rows

Comment: When you say it rolls over, do you just need to do a simple append or does the new data also update old data? For example: your old data goes to June 2023. Does the new data include June 2023 or does it start in July 2023?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this going from simplest and slowest to fastest and more complex. The larger your data, the more likely you're going to need to do an efficient version of this. SAS is generally very fast when it comes to dealing with big data, so I would take the simplest route first.

### **The easy way**

The simplest thing to do is to do a full overwrite of the dataset using a `where` statement. Here it is in the simplest form for a permanent dataset stored in the library `foo`:

```
data foo.have;
    set foo.have(where=(date < '30JUN2023'd))
        new
    ;
run;
```

Now all you need to do is convert that hardcoded date into a dynamic date. The easiest way to do that is to use `proc sql` and grab the smallest date of your new data and save it into a macro variable. In the example below, `&min_date` holds the smallest date from your new dataset you're reading. We'll just use that in our `where` statement:

```
proc sql noprint;
    select min(date)
    into :min_date
    from new;
quit;

data foo.have;
    set foo.have(where=(date < &min_date))
        new
    ;
run;
```

This is not the most efficient way of doing it since you have to read every single row of each dataset

### **The efficient way**

If you want to get more efficient, do the following:

1. Create an index on date for your primary dataset
2. Get the min date from your new data
3. Modify the primary dataset in-place to remove the old rows
4. Append the new rows to the primary dataset

The index on date will make it very fast for SAS to find and delete the rows of interest in your primary dataset.

```
/* 1. Create an index on the primary dataset in the library 'foo'.
      You only need to do this once. */
proc datasets lib=foo nolist;
    modify have;
        index create date;
quit;

/* 2. Get the min date from the new data */
proc sql noprint;
    select min(date)
    into :min_date
    from new;
quit;

/* 3. Remove the old data */
data foo.have;
    modify foo.have;
    where date GE &min_date;
    remove;
run;

/* 4. Append the new data */
proc append base=foo.have data=new force;
run;
```

Keep in mind that you must not overwrite the dataset with a set statement or sql create table statement. You must only use modify, append, or update operations. Doing otherwise will destroy the index and it will need to be recreated.